# How are you supposed to validate linked templates locally in Visual Studio?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I am trying to set up an ARM deployment using linked templates. I am working in a Visual Studio deployment project. Prior to deploying anything I of course want to validate the template.

However when using linked templates, the template provider expects linked templates to be hosted at a web-accessible endpoint, and complains if a local file path is provided. I don't have that, and I don't want to anyway, because the templates I want to validate are on my filesystem. Upon hitting `Validate` a series of the following errors are emitted to the Output window:

```
Validation returned the following errors:
16:49:13 - : Multiple error occurred: BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest. Please see details.
16:49:13 -   : The provided content link 'file:///the_real_path_to_my_template/templatename.template.json' is invalid or not supported. Content link must be an absolute URI not referencing local host or UNC path.
```

How are you supposed to validate a linked template, given this constraint?

Answer (score 2):

you cant really. you have to upload those and start the deployment passing in the links somehow. What I usually do i use the `uri()` and `deployment()` functions together to construct relative urls and use powershell script to upload all the templates to a storage account and invoke the deployment. so all the templates are in the same container, just with different names:

```
\
|- container X
 \
 |- linked.template.1.json
 |- linked.template.2.json
 |- parent.template.json
```

and the expression would be:

```
"[uri(deployment().properties.templateLink.uri, 'linked.template.1.json')]"
```

powershell is something like this:

```
$storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName yyy -StorageAccountKey 'xxx'
New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $containerName -Context $storageContext -Permission Blob

Get-ChildItem %somepath% -Filter *.json -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $_.FullName -Container $containerName -Context $storageContext -Force -ErrorAction Stop
}
```